# vb.net - ComboBox with a BindingSource and a different DataSource

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, bindingsource

In my form I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `BindingSource` that has a `DataSet` as `DataSource`. I also have some TextFields and ComboBoxes on the form that are bound to different columns in the `DataSet` through the `BindingSource`. The idea is that the values in the columns on the selected row in the `DataGridView` are reflected in the other controls on the form. Maybe I make it sound a bit complicated, but it's fairly easy to connect the TextFields, and also the ComboBoxes bound to tables in the dataset.

My problem is that this time I want to set the items in the `ComboBox` from an array and not from a table in the `DataSet`. This is what I've tried:

```
Me.ComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue",       Me.TblBindingSource, "ColumnName", True))

Dim ItemArray(2) As String
ItemArray(0) = ""
ItemArray(1) = "Default"
ItemArray(2) = "User-set"
ComboBox.DataSource = ItemArray
```

Now, this seems to work partially as the `ComboBox` is populated correctly, and I can select a value, and it appears in the `DataGridView`. But it doesn't update its selected value as I change rows in the `DataGridView`. The column `("ColumnName")` is a `ComboBoxColumn` that gets its item list in the way shown above, and it seams to work as expected.

If it wasn't clear; I have several ComboBoxes with similar functionality that works, but they are bound to a column in a `DataTable`, as follows:

```
Me.ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.Tbl1BindingSource, "WiDMethodX", True))
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = Me.Tbl2BindingSource
Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "SomeColumn"
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "SomeColumn"
```

If it matters, the `DataSet` comes from an `Access Database`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SelectedValue` is used in conjunction with the `ValueMember` property, but since your array list doesn't have descriptive fields, that won't work.

Try using `SelectedItem` for your binding:

```
Me.ComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedItem", _
                                      Me.TblBindingSource, "ColumnName", True))
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! But now something strange is happening; when I select a value in one row and then change rows one at a time, the value for that column is overwritten with the newly selected value. It doesn't happen if I change to a non-adjacent row!

Comment: Acually, I don't have to change the value in a combobox column; if I move up and down rows, the values in the combobox columns are changed to those of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this questions is old, but I had similar problem I resolved.  I bound the text property of the combo box to the binding source member that relates to the value member or display member of my combo box datasource. Make sure that you fill your data tables (for binding source and combo box datasource) AND bind your combo box to its datasource prior to databinding text of combo box.

```
Dim dtForBindingSource as DataTable
Dim bs as BindingSource
Dim dtForComboBox as DataTable

'Code to fill dtForBindingSource would go here

bs.DataSource = dtForBindingSource

'Code to fill dtForComboBox would go here

ComboBox.DataSource = dtForComboBox
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "ColumnToDisplay"
ComboBox.ValueMember = "ColumnXYZ"
```

'Now that datasources exist and combo box is set up I do databindings.

```
ComboBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "ColumnToDisplay")
```